# Evaluating a integral with a vector

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, vector-analysis

I was trying to solve this integral here but I am having trouble understanding if what I am doing is correct or not.

So the question says:

"Let $F(x,y) = x^2-y^2$. Evaluate:

a) $\int^{(2,8)}_{(0,0)} (\text{grad}\ F \cdot d\bf{s})$ along the curve $y=x^3$

b) $\oint \frac{\partial F}{\partial n}ds$ around the circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$. Here, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial n}$ is the directional derivative of $F$ along the outer normal and $dS$ = $|dS|$."

So I attempted part a.

I got the gradient as $\nabla F = <2x,2y>.$

If I parametrize the cubic function, I get $(x(t),y(t)) = (t,t^3) $. So then my integral goes from $t=0$ to $t=2$.

So as a result, my integral would be:

=$\int^{2}_{0} 2x\ dx - \int^{2}_{0} 2y\ dy$

=$\int^{2}_{0} 2t\ \frac{dx}{dt}dt - \int^{2}_{0} 2t^3\frac{dy}{dt}dt$

=$\int^{2}_{0} 2t(1)dt - \int^{2}_{0} 2t^3(3t^2)dt$

=$\int^{2}_{0} 2tdt - \int^{2}_{0} 6t^5 dt$

= -60

Is this right?

I am quite lost on how to do part b though. It's been a long time since I've taken multi variable calculus...

Comment: First, I think you missed a minus in the gradient of $F$.

Comment: in a) $\nabla F = 2x,- 2y.$  However, since $\nabla F$ is conservative.  $\int_a^b \nabla F \cdot \ dr = F(b) - F(a)$

Comment: One more item, you should substitute $y =t^3.$

Comment: Thanks! @DougM. I forgot to check if F was a conservative vector field. What about part b? I'm really not sure about that.

Comment: Then you have a conservative force going around a closed contour.  What do you know about that?

Comment: Okay now I haven't done multivariable calculus in a long time but since the force is conservative, it should be equal to 0 around a closed contour since it is simply connected? I am not sure if that is right though. @DougM

Comment: Exactly..........

Comment: Part b) is just 0 then? That seems incredibly easy... But alright, that makes sense I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do b) by first principles

the directional derivative.

$\nabla F \cdot \frac {u}{\|u\|}\\
\nabla F = 2x, -2y\\
\frac {u}{\|u\|} = \frac {(x,y)}{\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}}\\
\nabla F \cdot \frac {u}{\|u\|} = \frac {2x^2 - 2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

The contour:

$x = \cos t, y = \cos t\\
|dS| = dt$

$\int_\gamma \nabla F \cdot \frac {u}{\|u\|} |dS| = \int_0^{2\pi} 2\cos^2 t - 2\sin^2 t \ dt = 0$

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sue if I should post a separate question on this or not since that's against the rules and I did technically ask a different question. Hence I did not edit my post.